# Why it takes more energy to pull satellite towards Earth than pushing it away?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, orbital-motion, rocket-science, satellites

Newton's law of motion states that satellite in orbit stays in orbit unless external force is applied, so we shall apply the force through it's thruster to deorbit. Strangely, it takes more energy to pull it back to Earth so it can burn up in the atmosphere, what is happening? Is it the burn up parts that requires that much energy? I think I must have misread something here.

Comment: Pull how far? Push how far?

Comment: Perhaps it was a convoluted way to say that satellites are launched eastwards?

Comment: @user6760,    you initially read something wrong, since an "external" (gravitational) force is constantly applied to the satellite (otherwise it would not move in orbit) Nevertheless, the dependence of the radius of the orbit on the mass and speed of the satellite may lead to this effect, but it would be better, nevertheless, a link